# application crashes while running on device due to sqlite assertion

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ipad, ios-simulator, device

HI

I have developed the application on with sqlite Database .when i run the application in simulator it works perfect but when i tested with device application gets crashes.

this is my code
*** Assertion failure in -[sampleProjectAppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded], /Users/xxxx/Desktop/new/sampleProject/Classes/sampleProjectAppDelegate.m:66
2010-07-29 05:52:40.141 sampleProject[259:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'Operation could not be completed. Operation not permitted' .
2010-07-29 05:52:40.145 sampleProject[259:207] Stack: (
    852041337,
    861292157,
    852040821,
    850687039,
    9253,
    8563,
    827154211,
    827153345,
    827464035,
    827462369,
    827460907,
    819342131,
    851590557,
    851588321,
    827151529,
    827144691,
    8423,
    8348
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

Thanks..

Comment: any one is there to answer my question. stuck with this.
 can any one help in this????

Comment: Perhaps adding a bit of your code will help, not just the error message.

Comment: Small idea - One difference between the Simulator and a real device is that letter CASE (for some categories like file path)  is important on the device whereas on the simulator it is not. Hope it helps.